# Как Добавить видео в java и Хранение в MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

Есть программа которая позволяет юзера добавить фото и видео в сайт есть такой код который позволяет добавить фотография в сайт

> код для добавление фотографии

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\bankSystem\\" + fileName);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

хотел ради интереса добавить видео место фотографии дал такая ошибка

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (157246306) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
```

вот скажет что большая расширения но если резать видео для такого расширению видео длится до 1-2 секунд и это очень мало есть возможность чтобы добавить нормальную видеоролика ? если есть возможность и пользователь добавил видео как отображать этот видео на его стене ? для отображении фотографии  есть такой код

```
<c:forEach items="${product}" var="product">
 <img style="width:15px;height: 15px" src="/product/image?fileName=${product.picture}"> 
</c:forEach>
```

Весь код было обработана на Spring

Для хранения данных использую MYSQL база данных если все было хорошо пользователь добавил видео в каком типе можно хранить этот видео ?

Comment: А по существу, первая строчка кода подсказывает что вы используете Spring. Попробуйте мб это поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177873/max-limit-of-multipartfile-in-spring-boot

Comment: да забыл сказать сейчас исправлю но спасибо  вам

Comment: большие файлы лучше хранить на диске, в файлах. А в БД только расположение. В случае необходимости с диска вы можете быстро отдать файл клиенту средствами http сервера. А чтение его из БД для отдачи клиенту потребует гораздо больше ресурсов

Comment: ок спасибо большое за совет а в бд для расположение varchar пойдет ?

Comment: @Developer лучше LONGTEXT.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приветствую всем Особенно кто в комментариях дал какой то совет и помог мне ! я долго попробовал разные способы и нашел решения этой проблеме вот

> Это был то код который позволил добавить фото.На самом деле у MediaType - е есть такой метод `ALL_VALUE` этот метод позволяет добавить и гифы и все что угодно

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\bankSystem\\" + fileName);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

> Вот измененный код

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImageAsByteArray(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:\\bankSystem\\" + fileName);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.ALL_VALUE);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
```

> Чтобы отображать видео на странице пользователя нам поможет этот код

```
 <c:forEach items="${product}" var="product">
    ${product.name}
    <video style="width:300px;height: 300px" src="/product/image?fileName=${product.picture}">
</c:forEach>
```

> В MYSQL `varchar` тоже нормально но лучше `LONGTEXT`

Еще раз спасибо всем